# Windows Phone custom button click "area"

Tags: events, button, windows-phone, click

i have read a lot about this argument but i can't find a solution by myself about my specific problem.
I have create a custom button style in xaml (a circle with a letter inside) for a personal keyboard integrated into my app; the problem in that: the click event is lanched only when pressed the letter but i want make all button area sensible.
Here is my code:

```
<Style x:Key="ButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">
<Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
            <Grid>
                <Border CornerRadius="100" 
                BorderThickness="3" 
                BorderBrush="Black"
                Margin="1"
                Padding="0">
                    <Grid x:Name="ContentContainer">
                        <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Content}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
            </Grid>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

```
<Button HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Click="KeyboardButton_Click" Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle}" Content="Q" MinWidth="40" MinHeight="40" />


private void KeyboardButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you have no background set, so the button area is invisible for touch. Try to set `"Background"="Transparent"` in outside `Border`

Comment: Tested it with the code provided. It does work when setting the Background to Transparent in the Border Property.
`<Border CornerRadius="100" 
                BorderThickness="3" 
    Background="Transparent"
                BorderBrush="Black"
                Margin="1"
                Padding="0">`